# Subscript the numbers in a text in java

Tags: java, android

I'm making an android project about chemistry, and i need to display H2O with the "2" in a subscript.

Comment: May be it is in Java, but still in the Android context I suggest it is not duplicate.

Comment: dont use any `Html.fromHtml`: instead just read aboub `Spannable` interface and how to "set spans" (`SuperscriptSpan` in your case)

Answer (score 1):

Please pardon me for not making a comment, as I don't have enough rep to do so, but Adam Fręśko made a small mistake with his answer. His code states:

`tv.settext(Html.fromHtml("H2<sup>2</sup>0"))`

Which is extremely close to what we want (and the knowledge is certainly useful, esp. in chemistry), but for your question, it should be:

`tv.settext(Html.fromHtml("H2<sub>2</sub>0"))`

This should render as H<sub>2</sub>O.Do note the `<sub>` tag, which stands for subscript. He just accidently wrote `<sup>`, which stands for superscript.

Answer (score 0):

TextView support HTML something like this should be possible

```
tv.settext(Html.fromHtml("H2<sup>2</sup>0"))
tv.settext(Html.fromHtml("H2<sub>2</sub>0"))
```

tv.settext(Html.fromHtml("H<sup>2</sup>0"))

tv.settext(Html.fromHtml("H<sub>2</sub>0"))

Hmm it works even here :)

Comment: Erm ... you obviously slept through your high-school science classes :-).  The 2 should be a subscript not a superscript if you use accepted notation for chemical formulae.

Comment: @StephenC this is a new water type Lol ;) but else a nice way to solve it.

Comment: Oh sorry, i'm far from  native speeker